# Rotation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

I want to make a button in JavaScript that rotates 90 degrees when the method is clicked. what should I do? I wanted to do this with css but it didn't work. Please tell me how to do this with JS? (I know I'm very noob:/)

Comment: You wanted to do it with css but it didn't work, why don't you post your code with your question so people can inform you what you did wrong and learn from it. This way you also have a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is needed to answer your question. Also see the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to learn more about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for rotation

```js
document.querySelector("#img").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "rotate(7deg)";